# Hugo: How to redirect a list.html page to a single.html page

Tags: html, redirect, hugo

Let's say your site URL is http://example.com and you have a section called updates, so http://example.com/updates/update1, http://example.com/updates/update2

`content/updates/update1.md`

`content/updates/update2.md`

If you visit http://example.com/updates/ you get an empty page.

Does Hugo provide a way to redirect a section to a single page, so that http://example.com/updates -> http://example.com/updates/update1/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aliases: http://gohugo.io/content-management/urls#aliases

In content/updates/update1.md:

```
+++

aliases = [
    "/updates/"
]

+++
```